# getting started with rails NameError in ArticlesController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nameerror

I'm using this guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

I've been trying to solve a issue NameError in ArticlesController#index 
that showed up when i'm starting to add comments as a resource, controller and such.

The NameError in ArticlesController#index 
is telling me 
app/models/article.rb:1:in

```
<top (required)>'
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:3:in index'
```

Here is my code:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def index
@article = Article.all
end

def show
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def new
   @article = Article.new
end

def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

 if @article.save
  redirect_to @article
 else
    render 'new'
 end
end

def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])

  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy

  redirect_to articles_path
end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
  end
```

And this code:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
has_many :comments
validates :title, presence: true,
                  length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

Do I have all the code needed in the question?

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Answer (score -1):

looking at the error `<top (required)>'app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:3:inindex'`, I believe the issue is from your `index action` it should be

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
end
```

also change your model to

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

as your `Article` model should be inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` and not `ApplicationRecord`

Comment: ApplicationRecord is correct, see the tutorial page.